# How does one intercept Thunderbolt packets on macOS?

Tags: macos, reverse-engineering, device-driver, iokit

I'd like to reverse engineer the protocol of my Thunderbolt DP monitor in order to get volume / brightness control working natively in macOS.

For that I need to intercept sent Thunderbolt packets.

A Google search did not bring up anything helpful.

How do I do so? Might there be a tool similar to `lsusb`? Or does anyone know of a guide to get me started?

As far as I know Thunderbolt is basically PCIe over DP. Maybe I'm on the wrong track and rather should look to intercept PCIe? I'd appreciate clarification on this point, too.

Comment: Can you be more precise in your situation? Do you have a DisplayPort (DP) or Thunderbolt display? "Thunderbolt DP monitor" is ambiguous. (DP displays are plugged into a Thunderbolt port on modern Macs, but that does not make them Thunderbolt displays.) As you say you want to "reverse engineer the protocol" does this mean there already is working software for adjusting the controls? If not, how are you expecting to intercept packets that nobody is sending?

Comment: Finally, most displays don't allow modifying brightness from the host PC/Mac at all. Volume control frequently is not available either as HDMI/DisplayPort audio does not typically allow volume control.

Comment: Finally, a (hopefully) more constructive tip: If you're at all unsure about what kind of device you're dealing with, see if you can find it in IORegistryExplorer (download this app in the "Additional tools for Xcode" package from [the Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/); login required)